# Get regex pattern to match only digits with at least 2 decimal points python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use a lazy regex pattern in python to grab just the first number after a specified word, in this case Non-GAAP. However I only want figures that have at least 2 or more decimal places.

Here is my string:

```
s = 'Non-GAAP-2 net income of  with EPS of 1.21, up 23% from the fourth quarter of 2020.'
```

and my pattern is:

```
\bNon.*GAAP\b.*?\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b
```

This matches the number 2 after Non-GAAP when in fact I want the number 1.21.

How do I fix this pattern would you be able to explain the logic?

Thanks.

EDIT

If i want to edit this so I can choose any word to enter into the specified string, how would I change this as using `r` literal string fails and so does foramtted string because of the {2,}.

e.g.

```
s = f'\b{adjusted}\b.*?\b(\d+\.\d\{2,\})\b'
```

I have tried to backspace these characters but this also fails.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably need:

```
\bNon-GAAP\b.*?\b(\d+\.\d{2,})\b
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/M1qfS7/1)

---

- `\bNon-GAAP\b` - Your literal string 'Non-GAAP' inbetween word-boundaries;
- `.*?` - 0+ (Lazy) characters other than newline;
- `\b(\d+\.\d{2,})\b` - A capture group for 1+ digits followed by a literal dot and at least two more digits, inbetween word-boundaries.

---

Use this with `re.findall()`

```
import re
s = 'Non-GAAP-2 net income of  with EPS of 1.21, up 23% from the fourth quarter of 2020.'
print(float(re.findall(r'\bNon-GAAP\b.*?\b(\d+\.\d{2,})\b', s)[0]))
```

Prints:

```
1.21
```

---

EDIT:

Combining a variable with f-strings:

```
import re
s = 'Non-GAAP-2 net income of  with EPS of 1.21, up 23% from the fourth quarter of 2020.'
adjusted = 'Non-GAAP'
print(float(re.findall(fr'\b{adjusted}\b.*?\b(\d+\.\d{{2,}})\b', s)[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help bro. Please see edit above

Comment: @geds133, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your original regex is almost right, only the part which matches the decimals should be updated a bit:

```
\bNon.*GAAP\b.*?\b(\d+\.\d{2})\b
```

- `Non.*GAAP`: the original capturing group
- `.*?` 0+ characters
- `(\d+\.\d{2})` matches 1+ decimals, a literal dot and then exactly 2 decimals

[See a demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/M1qfS7/1)

You can also achieve the same result with a non-capturing group:

```
(?:Non-GAAP.*)(\d+\.\d{2})
```

- `(?:Non-GAAP.*)`: non-capturing group, the literal string 'Non-GAAP' and 0+ characters won't be included
- `(\d+\.\d{2,})`: capturing group to capture 1+ decimals, a literal dot and then exactly 2 decimals

[See a demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/T3UjN7/1)

---

**UPDATE**: for the updated question

To make the search string variable, you can just build the regex as you would a string:

```py
import re;

s = 'Non-GAAP-2 net income of  with EPS of 1.21, up 23% from the fourth quarter of 2020.';

search = 'Non-GAAP';

regex = r"(?:" + search + ".*)(\d+\.\d{2})";

print(float(re.findall(regex, s)[0]));
```

[See a demo repl.it here.](https://replit.com/@gcsecsey/OrangeTintedTechnology#main.py)

Comment: Thanks for the help bro. Please see edit above.

Comment: No problem, I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: Have added an example to help

Answer (score 0):

Use re for that

```
import re
s = 'Non-GAAP-2 net income of  with EPS of 1.21, up 23% from the fourth quarter of 2020.'

output  = re.sub(r'\d+\.\d+', '', s)
```

Comment: There is no check on `Non-GAAP`. What if there is a number with decimals before that substring? Also, why are you using `re.sub()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `\d*\.\d*` which will catch the first number with decimal places in your string

Comment: Or the first literal dot.